# Anyway to use variable in register name in NEON?

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

NEON extension registers can be viewed as 16 quadwords or 32 doublewords. In most programming, the specific register to be used is fixed. For example,

```
vmov.i8 d0, 0xff
vmov.i8 d1, 0xee
vmov.i8 d2, 0xdd
```

In my problem, the number of double word registers needed is dependent on the argument in the function call. For example, if the argument is 2, I need to do

```
vmov.i8 d0, 0xff
vmov.i8 d1, 0xee
```

If the argument is 4, I need to do

```
vmov.i8 d0, 0xff
vmov.i8 d1, 0xee
vmov.i8 d2, 0xdd
vmov.i8 d3, 0xcc
```

Is there anyway to choose a register whose name is based on a variable? i.e. something along this line(the following is not valid ARM assembly code):

```
mov r0, #1
vmov.i8 d{r0}, 0xff
```

Comment: Can you give more details on what you are trying to accomplish here?  Generally conditions in NEON are translated to bitwise logic so you could mask out parts of a register based on another value by doing a compare followed by an AND (for example).

Comment: With rare exception, ARM instructions are statically targeted and there is no way to conditionalize their operands.

Comment: I am trying to do byte matrix multiplication. The left matrix is 8 by 8 bytes and right one is 8 by n where n would be a variable, from 1 to 7. I want to see if I can write some generic code for all possible n (i.e. instead of first finding out what n is and then jumping to a label which specifically deals with that particular value). As different n requires different numbers of registers to store the right matrix, I want to see if it is possible to determine which registers to use based on the paramater n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to select target register at instruction level because instructions has target registers hard coded into themselves and its not feasible to create self modifying code with modern CPUs. See [ARM ARM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0406c/index.html) for any instruction encoding.

You can of course do this at high level with *if construct / conditional execution* in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute the last two instructions

```
vmov.i8 d2, 0xdd
vmov.i8 d3, 0xcc
```

on the condition that the argument is 4.

You could also write or generate code for all possible values of the argument.

You could probably also use macros if the argument is always a constant and not something computed.